# show drawable only once on map by tapping

Tags: android, google-maps

By class Overlay and calling method onTap from that class I can show drawables all over my map. The thing I want to do is just show one drawable when user taps on map ( the first tap) and not show again and again drawables in different places by tapping. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Any code? Config? Screenshot? Even proper explanation of the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question abit. I hope it is better now..

Answer (score 0):

```
override you onTap() method of Overlay

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
         Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
    CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext());
    forloop(setoflocations){
    GeoPoint srcpoint = new GeoPoint((int)( Double.parseDouble(lat) * 1E6),(int)( //latitude and longitude of user tapped location...
Double.parseDouble(lng)* 1E6));
    OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcpoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
    if(srcitemizedOverlay!=null && mapController!=null){
    srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapController.animateTo(point);
    animatePoint = point;
    }
    }
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();
    mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);

   // pop up a alert dialog here and ask user for confirmation

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "override you onTap() method of MapView". You mean from class Overlay? public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geopoint, MapView mapview)?

Comment: yes, you need to override onTap() method of Overlay class like I mentioned above..

Comment: I dont know what you are doing. Why there is a for loop there. and onTap method gets 2 argomants not one .. can you explaine me more plz

Comment: okay forget this code and follow this http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/add-marker-on-touched-location-using-google-map-in-android-example/

Comment: Thanks for the website. It solved my problem partially. In this solution, all the markers are same; but I want the first one (when map starts) different and want to keep it there. and the rest is like your solution: tap to another point and put a different marker there. How should i do the first part?